# need to extract a particular string present in multiple lines in java

Tags: java, string

```
public String ReplaceCline(String laddr) {
    if(text.contains("c="))
    {
    int a = text.length();



    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
          int var1 = text.indexOf("IP4", i);
          var1 = var1+ 4;
          int var2 = var1+15;

          text = text.replace(text.substring(var1, var2),laddr );

          i = var2;
    }

    }
    return text;
}
```

its throwing index out of bounds error.

have to replace ip address in the text sent by a device which is found in the "c=" line in the text.

Comment: Please remove your comment and put it as your question

Comment: Also, could you indicate where the index-out-of-bounds occures

Comment: Where does `text` come from?

Comment: and, how does laddr look like?

Comment: `int var2 = var1+15;` -> You should check the length of your String before performing a `substring(var1, var2);`

Comment: laddr is an ip address for example 172.27.150.61

Comment: and text is obtained from a softfone which can make sip based VoIP calls.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to replace the text.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("c=IN IP4 (?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(text);
if (matcher.find()) {
text = matcher.replaceAll(
        "c=IN IP4 "+laddr);
}
```

edit:
This assumes that the IN address is always preceded by IP4, and that the address is indeed an IP4 address. For compatibility with IP6 you need to augment the RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

The index out of bound should come from:

```
text = text.replace(text.substring(var1, var2),laddr );
```

Because of:

```
int var1 = text.indexOf("IP4", i);
var1 = var1+ 4;
int var2 = var1+15;
```

then var1 and var2 must be greater than i, which possibly exceed text.length()

double check that part should help.

Answer (score 0):

Try [StringUtils.subStringBetween](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringBetween%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
 StringUtils.substringBetween(input, "c=IN IP4 ", " ");
```

Output : `172.24.150.61`

Answer (score 0):

You also have to check the return value of indexOf:

`int var1 = text.indexOf("IP4", i);`

returns -1 if "IP4" is not found in your text.

Also you should not manually add numbers to the index.
A better way would be to use `text.indexOf(" ", var1+4);`
after checking the first return value.

But the best Solution is to use Regex or StringUtils as stated by @DeltaLima and @newuser